# trying to identify some orphan server's

Tags: powershell, dns, active-directory, powershell-3.0

I am trying to identify some orphan server's, these are windows servers in active directory I have a domain list of about 100 domain, I'm try to write a script where I can input a server name and it searches the domain names which I have stored in a text file, any assistance would be appriciated.

Comment: I think https://serverfault.com/ might be a better place to ask.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

1. Get the content of the file with - Get-Content C:\temp\file.txt
2. Do foreach loop for every server
3. Try to ping the server using Test-Connection
4. Use Get-ADComputer to pull computer object from AD and check when is the last time it updated it's password
5. If password is not changed in the last 30 days, append the computer name and Password Last Set date in orphan.csv file.

```
$serverlist = Get-Content C:\temp\file.txt
foreach ($server in $serverlist)
{
    if (-not (Test-Connection -Ping $server -Count 1 -Quiet)) 
    {
    Get-ADComputer $server -Properties PasswordLastSet | 
        Where {$_.Passwordlastset -le (Get-date).AddDays(-30)} | 
            Select-Object Name,PasswordLastSet | 
                Export-CSV C:\temp\orphan.csv -append -force -NoTypeInformation
    }
}
```